# UIView Width issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've got two table views of same height and width in UIView. I'm trying to place a divider(UIView of 1px width) in between tableviews as shown in picture but it is looking like 2px wide. i have tried placing the divider within .xib and programmatically as well but I'm getting the same issue. I want to achieve a divider with thickness same as a tableview cell divider line thickness.

```
UIView *vLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,1,500)];
vLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:207.0f/255.0f green:207.0f/255.0f blue:207.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
[self.view addSubview:vLine];
```

[image]

Comment: Try with lowering width param: CGRectMake(300,0,0.7,500), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, as its more robust:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
UIView *vLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 0, 1 / screenScale, 500)];
```

Answer (score 1):

For a retina device, 1 point will be 2px. Hence, use 0.5 as width for retina devices and 1 for non retina devices.

```
if(is_retina) {
     [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,0.5,500)];
} else {
     [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,1,500)]    
}
```

Comment: One thing I would probably share as well is the setting of `is_retina` otherwise +1

Answer (score 0):

Try setting pattern image with 1px width containing 0.5 px clear color and other 0.5px with your separator color.

An example pattern image is given below.

```
 UIView *vLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,0,1,500)];
    vLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPatternImage.png"]];
```

Here your pattern image should be of 1px width containing 0.5 px clear color and other 0.5px with your separator color in normal screen. Try ith with the image provided below.[
[image]
]

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are talking about. Set a pattern image, what?

Comment: I have put an image in between the brackets []. since it is of size 2 x 2 it is not visible, but you cane save it by right click.

Answer (score -1):

The height of the native table view separator is 0.5 pixels. Simply adjust your frame to:

```
UIView *vLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300.0f,0.0f,0.5f,500.0f)];
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? The other answers here about screen scale are incorrect, UIView's frame is given in points, not pixels. Points adjust to the scale of the screen in pixels when rendered.